# Showing a bound exists

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I was able to derive the following differential equations I have to work with for a function $V$:

$$ \begin{align*}
  dV(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) &= \left(x_1^2-1\right)\left[(1-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2)-c_{21}x_2^2+e_{31}x_3^2+e_{41}x_4^2 \right]\\
    &+  \left(x_2^2-1\right)\left[(1-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2)+e_{12}x_1^2-c_{32}x_3^2-c_{42}x_4^2 \right]\\
    &+  \left(x_3^2-1\right)\left[(1-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2)-c_{13}x_1^2+e_{23}x_2^2+e_{43}x_4^2 \right]\\
    &+  \left(x_4^2-1\right)\left[(1-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2)-c_{14}x_1^2+e_{24}x_2^2-c_{34}x_3^2 \right] dt\\
\end{align*}$$

What I would like to do is find constants $c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$ so that:

$$dV(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \leq c_0+c_1x_1^2+c_2x_2^2+c_3x_3^2+c_4x_4^2 dt$$

All the parameters $e_{ij}$ and $c_{ij}$ are positive, and each $x_i >0$ as well. Clearly this bound may not exist if the $e_{ij}$ are too large since the equations may explode, so the suitable condition  to prevent this is suppose to be $\Pi e_{ij} < \Pi c_{ij}$. What that should do is somehow create enough push from the negative terms to prevent explosion. However, I have been unable to use that condition and show the bound I'm looking for exists. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> Clearly this bound may not exist if the $e_{ij}$ are too large since the equations may explode, so the suitable condition  to prevent this is suppose to be $\Pi e_{ij} < \Pi c_{ij}$. What that should do is somehow create enough push from the negative terms to prevent explosion.

The condition $\Pi e_{ij} < \Pi c_{ij}$ is not sufficient. For instance, put $x_1=x_2=1$ and $x_3=x_4=x$.

Then when $x$ tends to infinity, $$dV(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(x^4(e_{42}-c_{34}-4)+O(x^3))dt$$

which is asymptotically greater than $(c_0+c_1+c_2 +(c_3+c_4)x^2)dt$, provided  $e_{42}-c_{34}-4>0$. To assure this condition along with  $\Pi e_{ij} < \Pi c_{ij}$ we can put, for instance, $e_{42}=6$, all others $e_{ij}=1$,  $c_{34}=1$, and all others $c_{ij}=2$.

*Update*. It seems the following.

For the convenience we extend the domain of $c_{ij}$ and $e_{ij}$, by putting $c_{ij}=c_{ji}$, $e_{ij}=e_{ji}$, and $c_{ii}=c_{jj}=0$ for all $i$ and $j$. Consider  symmetric matrices $C=\|c_{ij}\|$, $E=\|e_{ij}\|$ and $D=\|2_{ij}\|$. Put $A=(C+D-E)/2$. Then

$$dV(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(-4+5|x|^2-x^TAx)dt,$$ 
where $$x^T=(x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2, x_4^2)$$  and $$|x|=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+ x_4^2.$$

So the function $dV$ is quadratic bounded by a function of  a form $C_1+C_2(|x|)dt$ iff its quartic part $-x^TAx$ is non-positive for all $x$.  The sufficient conditions for this are non-negativity or a non-negative definiteness of the matrix $A$. The matrix $A$ is non-negative iff each $c_{ij}+2\ge e_{ji}$ for each $i$ and $j$.

Comment: But the example you gave would violate the condition that "each $x_i >0$ as well". In your example, to derive the $V$, the other $c_{ij}$ and $e_{ij}$ really wouldn't exist, or at least serve no role, so the condition would really just imply that $c_{34}>e_{42}$, and thus there's no way I'd have $e_{42}-c_{34}-4 > 0$. This paper suggests the condition is enough: https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maslaq/papers/hcstab2.pdf (see remark 3.3), of which this paper refers to the previously mentioned one: https://math.la.asu.edu/~dieter/papers/Chaos_hc_network.pdf

Comment: @Brenton I can easily avoid these counterarguments, see my rewritten answer.

Comment: Would the condition that each $c_{ij} > e_{ji}$ make it work? I think it does if I do it that way

Comment: @Brenton Do you mean each $c_{ij}$ is greater than each $e_{kl}$, because the condition $e_{42}-c_{34}-4>0$ seems to be compatible with each $c_{ij}>e_{ji}$?

Comment: Yes essentially, I had expanded out the entire equation and combined things together that each term with the $-4$ would have one of the c's greater than the e. It took awhile to write out and I'm a bit lazy to retype it all out

Comment: @Brenton Oops, you are right, there should be $e_{43}$ instead of $e_{42}$. So it seems that the condition each $c_{ij}+2\ge e_{ji}$ make it work. I am going to write details later.

Comment: That looks similar to what I had when I worked it out in detail. Feel free to still write details. I'd be quite interested in comparing our results

Comment: @Brenton See the update of the answer.